# What is the value for custom endpoint when connect AWS secret manager from CAS?

Tags: cas

I have a problem when I try to connect AWS secret manager from CAS follow this https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.5.x/configuration/Configuration-Server-Management-SpringCloud-AmazonSecretManager.html.

`ERROR [org.apereo.cas.config.AmazonSecretsManagerCloudConfigBootstrapConfiguration] - <Received an UnknownHostException when attempting to interact with a service. See cause for the exact endpoint that is failing to resolve. If this is happening on an endpoint that previously worked, there may be a network connectivity issue or your DNS cache could be storing endpoints for too long. SdkClientException.java:build:102 HelpfulUnknownHostExceptionInterceptor.java:modifyException:59 ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:modifyException:202`

I don't know what exactly the value I need to set for the endpoint, I've tried using these endpoints but it's still not working do I need to do any step to create it in AWS?

- com.amazonaws.{region}.secretsmanager
- https://{region}.console.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/secret?name={secret-name}&region={region}
- arn:aws:secretsmanager:{region}:{account-id}:secret:{secret-name}

Thanks.